# How do I get my bash script to assign unique usernames automatically to new users?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm a beginner writing a bash script designed to create new users. It asks the user whether to create or remove users. When creating, it asks how many, and then it useradds users with the username 'user1', 'user2' etc and a welcome file in their home dir. I've got it doing that, the loops are working, but it won't repeat, because it seems to confuse the id integer with the number of users it needs to create. In other words, if I first create user1 and user2 with this script, and then run it again to create 1 or 2 more, it will respond with 'user1 already exists' or 'user2 already exists' and it won't create two new accounts. If I ask it to create 3 accounts, it will create 'user3', but nothing else.

What I need it to do is see that user1 and 2 are taken, and then add 1 to the username and automatically assign 'user3' and 'user4' to the next two accounts created, and so on. The loop I have creating users is this:

```
if [[ $NUMBER -lt 20 && $ACTION == "create" ]]
then
        until [[ $NUMBER -eq 0 ]]
        do
           i=$(($i+1))
           USERNAM="user$i"
           useradd -s /usr/bin/bash -m $USERNAM;
           cat <<-EOF> /home/$USERNAM/welcome.txt
           Welcome to your new Linux account!
EOF
           let NUMBER=$NUMBER-1;
           done;
fi
```

This might not be the cleanest way to achieve this, but it seems to work. I've tried several different ways of getting it to build on previously created usernames instead of trying to overwrite the old usernames. This is my current attempt:

```
if id -u "$USERNAME" >/dev/null 2>&1;
then
        until [[ $NUMBER -eq 0 ]]
        do 
        i=$(($i++))
        useradd...
```

The rest of this loop is the same as the first. This doesn't work, obviously. Can anyone tell me how to write this script in such a way that it will automatically +1 on an existing username for any new accounts it creates?

Comment: Just don't add the user, if `USERNAM` is already taken!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put another loop around

```
           i=$(($i+1))
           USERNAM="user$i"
```

to skip over existing users:

```
          while
            i=$(($i+1))
            USERNAM="user$i"
            id $USERNAM
          do :
          done
```

Comment: I'm assuming that the useradd code follows do in this while loop. When I run the script like that, it says id: 'user1': no such user for both user1 and 2. So it gets stuck on id. Can I add a conditional or something, like if user doesn't exist, create user? Or have I used the while loop incorrectly?

Comment: You're assuming wrong - _the useradd code follows_ `done`. How can it say _id: 'user**1**': no such user for **2**_? What do you mean by _it gets stuck on id_? After it says `no such user`, it proceeds to the `useradd` and adds that user. Have you checked whether the users exist afterwards?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that 'user1': no such user is shown for every newly added user but changes to 'user2' or 'user3', depending. I corrected the script and placed the useradd code after done, and now it does work! I ran it for 3 new users, and then 2 new users, and user1-5 were created, so that works! It does show me the 'id: no such user' output, which isn't necessarily a problem, but I'll try to redirect that output so it doesn't show. It's just a confirmation that id was executed and the user doesn't exist, before the script goes on to create that user, as you mention. Thanks very much!